# Google Earth Engine Python API, converting ee.list to Python list

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am using Google Earth Engine's Python API which provides result objects such as ee.number, ee.list, ee.image. I do not know which detail I am missing but the following code:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MCD43A4_NDVI')
print collection.toList(10)
```

returns:

```
ee.List({
  "type": "Invocation", 
    "arguments": {
    "count": 10, 
    "collection": {
      "type": "Invocation", 
      "arguments": {
        "id": "MODIS/MCD43A4_NDVI"
      }, 
     "functionName": "ImageCollection.load"
    }
  }, 
  "functionName": "Collection.toList"
})
```

How can I get an actual Python list? Using any method displayed by

```
print dir(collection.toList(10))
```

just adds to this JSON output.

Comment: what do you want the list to contain?

Comment: If I run the code in its JS version in the sandbox I get a JSON object containing a list of image names. But maybe that is already the solution, I will see whether the ee.list object has a way to return that JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code returns a list of dictionaries containing the desired information:

```
import ee
ee.Initialize()

collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MCD43A4_NDVI')
list = collection.toList(10)
print list.getInfo()
```

Comment: You have to be careful with getInfo() function because every time you call it you make a request to the server and thus slow down the process and consume EE capacity. The recomendation is to use it only if it is completally necessary.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. But that is the point, I am importing the list to further process it client side.

Comment: I supposed it, I also work with the Python API and use getInfo() quite often. I just commented not only for you but for everyone who reads this and finds it helpful.